# Masking Entity Framework query result based on condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0 and MVC and I have one of the following model:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String SocialNumber {get;set;}
}

public class Organization
{
    [Key]
    public Guid? OrgId { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Members { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm getting this data by doing something like

```
bool hideData = false;
var sResult = DBContext.Organization.FirstOrDefault(s => s.OrgId == inputID)
```

Is there an elegant way for me to set the SocialNumber = "######" when hideData is true and show the value when it is false?

Before you tell me that I can just loop through the object and set them explicitly, the reason I don't want to do this because I simpled down the above example, in reality, my class is buried deep in many many objects.

Comment: You should create a new class `OrganizationViewModel` (with whatever properties you need) and then populate it as necessary.

Comment: I'm sort of doing that already, but I was hoping to be able to do it at the Person class level so that any future use of this object doesn't have to implement the same logic.  Note that the class Person is used by many many other Models.

Comment: Do you really need to mask in the data, or is it more appropriate to mask in the view? If it's in the view, then your viewmodel class may be the best place to do it.

Comment: I was thinking of mask the data so I don't have to do this in multiple views that use this object throughout my applications.